# Sort elements of an array in ascending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array in ascending order. For some reason it only performs the for loop once. Why doesn't it keep going until everything is sorted?

It's for an assignment so I am not allowed to use existing sort methods. I'm supposed to write the method myself.

```
public class Sudoku {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 1, 4, 3, 5, 2 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortArray(a)));
    }

    public static int[] sortArray(int[] nonSortedArray) {
        int[] sortedArray = new int[nonSortedArray.length];
        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < nonSortedArray.length - 1; i++) {
            if (nonSortedArray[i] > nonSortedArray[i + 1]) {
                temp = nonSortedArray[i];
                nonSortedArray[i] = nonSortedArray[i + 1];
                nonSortedArray[i + 1] = temp;
                sortedArray = nonSortedArray;
            }
        }

        return sortedArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: "For some reason it only performs the for loop once. " -- where in your program did you tell it to perform it more than once? The program will will only do what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static int[] sortArray(int[] nonSortedArray) {
        int[] sortedArray = new int[nonSortedArray.length];
        int temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < nonSortedArray.length - 1; j++) {// added this for loop, think about logic why do we have to add this to make it work

        for (int i = 0; i < nonSortedArray.length - 1; i++) {
            if (nonSortedArray[i] > nonSortedArray[i + 1]) {
                temp = nonSortedArray[i];
                nonSortedArray[i] = nonSortedArray[i + 1];
                nonSortedArray[i + 1] = temp;
                sortedArray = nonSortedArray;

            }
        }
        }
        return sortedArray;
    }
```

**output:**[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

**or**

```
//making use of j

public static int[] sortArray(int[] nonSortedArray){
    int[] sortedArray = new int[nonSortedArray.length];
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i <= nonSortedArray.length; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < nonSortedArray.length; j++)
        {
            if (nonSortedArray[i] > nonSortedArray[j]) 
            {
                temp = nonSortedArray[i];
                nonSortedArray[i] = nonSortedArray[j];
                nonSortedArray[j] = temp;
                sortedArray = nonSortedArray;
            }
        }
    }
    return sortedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 arr = new int[Item];
  Arrays.sort(arr);
```

*Built in function in java to sort array in asceding order.*

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort an array using a single loop. You would be needing two loops to ensure that the elements are in sorted order.

```
public static int[] sortArray(int[] nonSortedArray) 
{
    int[] sortedArray = new int[nonSortedArray.length];
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < nonSortedArray.length-1; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < nonSortedArray.length; j++)
        {
            if (nonSortedArray[i] > nonSortedArray[j]) 
            {
                temp = nonSortedArray[i];
                nonSortedArray[i] = nonSortedArray[j];
                nonSortedArray[j] = temp;
                sortedArray = nonSortedArray;
            }
        }
    }
    return sortedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will sort an array in ascending order

```
int arr[]={33,3,4,5,1};
Arrays.sort(arr);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString (arr));
```

output will:-[1,3,4,5,33]

Answer (score 0):

Sorting array in ascending order

```
private static int[] sort(int[] array) {
        int[] new_array = new int[array.length];
        int count=0;

        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<array.length+i;j++) {
                if(array[i]>=array[j%array.length])
                    count++;
            }

            for(int loc=count; loc>0;loc--) {
                if(new_array[loc]==0)
                {
                    new_array[loc]=array[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            count=0;                            
        }

        return new_array;
    }
```